# Search for zero in 2D array and make a corresponding row and col 0

Tags: arrays, ruby, logic

This is my code, which works, but it's too big. I want to refactor it.

```
req_row = -1
req_col = -1

a.each_with_index do |row, index|
  row.each_with_index do |col, i|
     if col == 0
        req_row = index
        req_col = i
        break
     end
  end
end

if req_col > -1 and req_row > -1
  a.each_with_index do |row,index|
    row.each_with_index do |col, i|
      print (req_row == index or i == req_col) ? 0 : col
       print " "
    end
    puts "\r"
  end
end
```

Input: 2D Array

```
1  2  3  4 
5  6  7  8
9  10 0 11
12 13 14 15
```

Required output:

```
1  2  0  4 
5  6  0  8
0  0  0  0
12 13 0  15
```

Comment: This will reduce your code `row.index(0)`

Comment: It's worth noting that your program only displays the zeroes, it doesn't actually alter the arrays.

Comment: @tadman can you help how to do that

Comment: I'm assuming the answer should be able to handle arrays that contain multiple zero's right? Your code as it stands can not handle this case.

Comment: I would like to offer some advice on posing questions: 1) Always begin by explaining what you are trying to do in words. Here, you might say, "If a two-dimensional array contains a zero, I would like to convert all elements in the associated row and column to zero". (That's not quite precise, as arrays don't have rows and columns, but it get's the idea across.) 2) Add an example with the expected result. You've done that, but the example should refer to valid Ruby objects. In part, that is so that readers can cut and paste. Also, give input values names, so  answers can refer to them (cont..)

Comment: (cont..) Here you might have `arr = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],..]`. That way, answers can be like `arr.each_with_object...`, without having to state what `arr` is. The expected result should also be a valid Ruby object, but you don't have to give it a name (e.g., `[[1,2,0,4],...]`). 3) After you've done the foregoing, present your code and explain what the problem is. As it is now, the reader is asked to go through your code to figure out what you are trying to do (cont..).

Comment: (cont..) 4) When readers ask questions, answer them by editing your question. Here readers want to know if you are only concerned with the "first" zero in the array or all of them. You need to clarify that. When editing, it is often good practice to indicate that you are doing so. For example, you could write, "Edit: I am only concerned with the first zero in `arr.flatten`." or "Edit: I wish to zero all rows and columns that contain a zero."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised the [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class is not used more:

```
a = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
     [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
     [ 9, 10,  0, 11],
     [12, 13, 14, 15]]

require 'matrix'

m = Matrix.rows(a)
  #=> Matrix[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 0, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]

r, c = m.index(0)
  #=> [2, 2]

Matrix.build(m.row_count, m.column_count) {|i,j| (i==r || j==c) ? 0 : m[i,j]}.to_a
  #=> [[ 1,  2, 0,  4],
  #    [ 5,  6, 0,  8],
  #    [ 0,  0, 0,  0],
  #    [12, 13, 0, 15]]
```

Note `Matrix` objects are immutable. To change individual elements you must create a new matrix.

A slight modification is required if you wish to do this for every zero in the matrix:

```
a = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
     [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
     [ 9, 10,  0, 11],
     [ 0, 13, 14, 15]]

require 'set'

m = Matrix.rows(a)
  #=> Matrix[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 0, 11], [0, 13, 14, 15]]

zero_rows = Set.new
zero_columns = Set.new
m.each_with_index { |e,i,j| (zero_rows << i; zero_columns << j) if e.zero? }
zero_rows
  #=> #<Set: {2, 3}> 
zero_columns
  #=> #<Set: {2, 0}>     

Matrix.build(m.row_count, m.column_count) do |i,j|
  (zero_rows.include?(i) || zero_columns.include?(j)) ? 0 : m[i,j]
end.to_a
  #=> [[0, 2, 0, 4],
  #    [0, 6, 0, 8],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I've been a Rubyist for a while now and never came across the Matrix class, very cool.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
req_row = req_col = -1

a.each_with_index do |row, index|
    req_col = row.index(0) # searching index having value 0.
    if req_col
        req_row =  index 
        break
    end 
end
a.each_with_index do |row,index|
    row.each_with_index do |col, i|
        print ((req_row == index or i == req_col) ? 0 : col).to_s + " "
    end
    puts "\r"
end
```

Comment: this code is working fine but can we reduce one more loop to search '0'

Answer (score 1):

Based on the title of your question, here's solution that searches for positions of the zero values (`fixate`), then actually zeros out the appropriate row and column (`clear`, more aligned with the contents of your question):

```
def fixate matrix, search=0, replace=0
  rcs = []

  matrix.each_with_index do |row,r|
    row.each_with_index do |col,c|
      rcs << [ r, c ] if col == search
    end
  end

  rcs.each do |(row, col)|
    clear matrix, row, col, replace
  end

  matrix
end

def clear matrix, row, col, val=0
  matrix[row].map! { |_| val }     # Clear rows
  matrix.each { |r| r[col] = val } # Clear columns
  matrix
end
```

Quick test:

```
fixate [               # [
  [ 1,  2,  3,  4  ],  #   [ 1,  2,  0, 4  ],
  [ 5,  6,  7,  8  ],  #   [ 5,  6,  0, 8  ],
  [ 9,  10, 0,  11 ],  #   [ 0,  0,  0, 0  ],
  [ 12, 13, 14, 15 ]   #   [ 12, 13, 0, 15 ]
]                      # ]
```

Comment: Loos good, but the `return` statements are pretty heavy handed by Ruby standards. It's implicit if at the end of a method. Not sure why `matrix.size.times` was used when `matrix.each { |r| r[col] = val }` would do the same job.

Comment: Factored in your suggestions.

Comment: Looking pretty lean and mean now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
zero_rows=[]
a.map do |col| 
   col.each_with_index do |el, index|
     zero_rows.push(index) if el==0 
   end
   col.fill(0) if col.include?(0)
end

a.map{|col| zero_rows.each{|index| col[index]=0} }
```

First, use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to iterate through the columns and [`fill`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-fill) them with zeros if they contain at least one 0. but, while doing so, add the indexes which contain a 0 to the `zero_rows` array.

Afterwards, iterate through the array once more and set the indexes of each column that match an index in `zero_rows` to 0.

You may know the `map` method as `collect`. They do the same thing.

### Side Note:

**If an array contains multiple zero's this code will zero out every applicable column.**  OP's example and some other answers here will only zero out the first column in which a 0 is found. If this is the behavior you are expecting, then see @Doguita's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this code is better than the other answers. I will test it later:

```
ary = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 0, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
col = nil
row = ary.index{ |a| col = a.index(0) }
ary.each_with_index { |a, i| i == row ? a.fill(0) : a[col] = 0 } if col

p ary
# => [[1, 2, 0, 4], [5, 6, 0, 8], [0, 0, 0, 0], [12, 13, 0, 15]]
```

Obs: This answer assumes there's only one 0 to search in the array

Comment: this doesn't work if an array contains more than one 0

Comment: @LukeP I know, but it fits in the OP example. Are you sure you need to search for more than one 0?

Comment: I can only assume so. A good answer should also be more robust, so as to be more helpful to future readers. I will ask for clarification in the comments though.

Comment: In the mean time, i can only undo my down vote if you edit your answer. (SO has locked my vote)